# Oracle simple INSERT statement taking ages

Tags: .net, oracle, .net-4.0, oracle10g, oledb

I have the below SQL which is getting executed with OleDBConnection and OleDBCommand and its taking forever and eventually times out and I dont know why.  Before this script gets executed others are executed and they are fine. I don't know what's so special about this one.

```
begin
      insert into messages (message_id,message,store_in_log, message_group) 
         values (25000,'Production Floor','False','Locations');
      insert into messages (message_id,message,store_in_log, message_group) 
          values (25001,'Building 4 – A','False','Locations');
      insert into messages (message_id,message,store_in_log, message_group) 
          values (25002,'Building 3 – A','False','Locations');
      insert into messages (message_id,message,store_in_log, message_group) 
          values (25003,'Building 4 – B','False','Locations');
      insert into messages (message_id,message,store_in_log, message_group) 
          values (25004,'Building 4 – C','False','Locations');
      insert into messages (message_id,message,store_in_log, message_group) 
          values (25005,'Building 4 – D','False','Locations');
      insert into messages (message_id,message,store_in_log, message_group) 
          values (25006,'Quarantine','False','Locations');
      insert into messages (message_id,message,store_in_log, message_group) 
          values (25007,'Small Area','False','Locations');
end;
```

VB Code with OLEDB Connection:

```
        Dim sc As Script
        Dim C As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(CnStr)
        Dim Cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim sql As String
        For Each sc In s               
        sql = sc.OracleScript               

        Cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, C)
        Try
           Cmd.Connection.Open()
           Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
           Cmd.Connection.Close()
           Cmd.Dispose()
           Cmd = Nothing
        End Try

        Next
```

Comment: can you show your .NET / C# code where you open the connection and execute the OleDbCommand? any reason why you are connecting with OleDb and not with Oracle native clients?

Comment: Do you have an index on `store_in_log` or `message_group`? How much data is in the table already?

Comment: @Thilo: The table has about 30 rows in it

Comment: The insert statement is really simple. Have you [check for locks](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_locked_rows_user_locks.htm)?

Comment: @DavidePiras Have added code but as I say previous scripts are fine with this code

Comment: Jon you should have some logging in the catch block, not just hide and forget any exception. when you debug this on which line execution hangs and takes the longest?

Comment: Maybe another transaction inserting the exact same primary key values? That would block your transaction inserting them.

Comment: @DavidePiras I have in production, I took it out here

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am a single user

Comment: @Jon: single user does not necessarily mean a single transaction. Do you have another SQL tool or application running that does the same insert (and has not yet committed it)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name nope. this is a simple little program

Comment: @danihp Make that your answer! Although I found the script here to find and kill it. http://campus-codemonkeys.blogspot.com/2007/01/killing-oracle-session-to-remove-lock.html

Comment: Is your little program able to create a connection to the database at all? On which line does the "timeout" occur and what's the exact error message?

Comment: ok, I have posted my comment as an answer to check it as solution in order to help other developers. See you!

Comment: @codo It was on ExecuteNonQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insert statement is really simple. [Have you check for locks](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_locked_rows_user_locks.htm)?

Comment: Thanks although I found an alternative way if finding and killing locks http://campus-codemonkeys.blogspot.com/2007/01/killing-oracle-session-to-remove-lock.html